# sql server friday date from week number

Tags: sql-server, date

I have the following table in MS SQL Server that has year number and week number:

```
Year               Week
-----             ------
2015               33
2014               41
2016               40
```

How can I get a 3rd column that has the date of the corresponding Friday for each row? So, week 33 of 2015 should return: Friday, August 14, 2015. I have tried using Datefromparts(year, 1, week*7-1), because an equivalent function in Excel using Date seemed to do the trick in Excel, but Datefromparts doesn't work with integers outside valid ranges.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016
DECLARE @Week INT = 40

SELECT DATEADD(dd, 5, (DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR)) + (@Week-1), 6)))
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work with the year 2021. The first week of 2021 starts on 04/01/2021.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetFirstDateOfWeek] (@YearNum int, @WeekNum int)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @FirstWeekDay As Date;

SET @FirstWeekDay = dateadd (week, @WeekNum, dateadd(year, @YearNum-1900, 0)) - 4 - datepart(dw, dateadd(week, @WeekNum, dateadd (year, @YearNum-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1

RETURN @FirstWeekDay
END
```